# : cannot connect to X server python cv2

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

When I am using cv2.imshow() while running [SLIC](https://github.com/jayrambhia/superpixels-SLIC/blob/master/SLICcv.py), I get the below error.

> : cannot connect to X server

I am running this program on a remote machine with GPU access. I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53357075/cv2-cannot-connect-to-x-server) and a few other related answers but none of them solve my issue. Can you suggest on how to proceed with this.

Comment: This was answered and it works for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8606231/7326568

Answer (score 5):

This helped me :
In your python script add these lines :

```
import os
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
```

This problem means that your code is trying (and failing) to connect to an X server -- a GUI environment -- presumably being forwarded over your SSH session.

Answer (score -2):

You have to allow the root user access to the X Server which some remote machines wont allow. Try this

```
xhost local:root
sudo DISPLAY=$DISPLAY gedit /etc/profile
```